# Link/Web CSV into datagridview

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview

I know how to populate datagridview from local CSV, but how can I populate Datagridview from a link containing CSV (e.g. [http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=desc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&view=raw&r=706201&denominatorView=raw&number=3](http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS%3aAAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=desc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&view=raw&r=706201&denominatorView=raw&number=3))

I have this code for a local CSV, first line should be changed to point to a link, but I don't know how.

```
 Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\finviz.csv")

        TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {","}

        While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
            Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()

            If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
                Dim i As Integer

                For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1
                    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
                Next
            End If

            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row1)
        End While
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
    Dim myUri As New Uri("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/ReportProcess4CSV.html?&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=USD&reportType=is&period=12&dataType=A&order=desc&columnYear=5&rounding=3&view=raw&r=706201&denominatorView=raw&number=3")
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(myUri), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim receiveStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

    Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(receiveStream)
    TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
        Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()

        If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
            Dim i As Integer

            For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" & i + 1, "Column" & i + 1)
            Next
        End If

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(Row1)
    End While

    receiveStream.Close()
    response.Close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's much faster then downloading file first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add csv text downloading code before this line:

```
Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\finviz.csv")
```

Either use `WebClient`'s [DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) on separate thread or [DownloadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx) (that uses its own separate thread) or [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes to download the csv before parsing it with `TextFieldParser`.

Also, don't hardcode the file name.

Comment: I was using this : Dim strResult As String = RequestWebData(LINK) for parsing individual strings from CSV, but delimiter doesn't work with strResult. Don't know how to implement that line with code above?

Comment: Didn't have any success with WebClient myWebClient.DownloadFile(strResult) : Overload resultion failed error.