# First row as header in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, row

Imported data from CSV to datagridview has header in first row, I could hide that row and name header for every column, problem is that data table has 68 columns. Is it possible to make first row header without having to do that manually for every single column?

Comment: how did you imported csv to DGV ? ..

Comment: In lack of better solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081285/link-web-csv-into-datagridview I've downloaded file to local drive with DownloadFile, then used file to populate datagridview (code in link). Can you please help me with this problem (header)?

Comment: How if you changed `For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1` to `For i = 1 To Row1.Count - 1` ... ?

Comment: @matzone Doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work ? .. may I know what ?

Comment: Changing For i = 0 to For i = 1 ...default header is still there and row(with header text) is still the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting and help from user: ooopsoft :

```
  Dim TextFieldParser1 As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(receiveStream)
    TextFieldParser1.Delimiters = New String() {","}
    Dim newline() As String = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()

    While Not TextFieldParser1.EndOfData
        Dim Row1 As String() = TextFieldParser1.ReadFields()

        If DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0 AndAlso Row1.Count > 0 Then
            Dim i As Integer

            For i = 0 To Row1.Count - 1
                DataGridView1.Columns.Add(newline(i), newline(i))

            Next
        End If
    End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Your datagrid should have taken all column names from CSV, if not then you need to have a look at this great article. It will help you a lot. This is the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader).

Comment: Column names are in first row but I would like for them to be in header instead of column1 column2 and so on... regarding your link I am not able to read C#

Comment: Ok, then try this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16951/Populating-data-from-a-CSV-file-to-a-DataGridView

Comment: Using code from  link above, after opendialog/csv selected I get this error : No row can be added to a DGV control that does not have columns